# python: how to explain the following codes

Tags: python

Tested on my local machine:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:33:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> q=[2,3]
>>> p=[1,q,4]
>>> p[1].append('test')
>>> q
[2, 3, 'test']
>>> hex(id(q))
'0x7fabfa5c2b90'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> hex(id(p))
'0x7fabfa5c2b48'
>>> hex(id(p[1]))
'0x7fabfa5c2b90'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> p.append(q)
>>> p
[1, [2, 3, 'test'], 4, [2, 3, 'test']]
>>> p[1].append('test2')
>>> p
[1, [2, 3, 'test', 'test2'], 4, [2, 3, 'test', 'test2']]
>>>
```

At beginning, I thought when generating p, a copy of q is copied into p.

**Any document can help understand the above behaviour? I have no idea why python did this? and In which cases, this behaviour will happen?**

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly a document, but Brandon Rhodes covers this and much more on how names and references work in Python in his talk [Names, Objects, and Plummeting From The Cliff](http://pyvideo.org/pyohio-2011/pyohio-2011-names-objects-and-plummeting-from.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you append `q` to `p`, you are not creating a copy of `q`, you are actually appending a reference to the object that the name `q` currently points to.  Therefore, when you append to `q` (or in this case `p[1]`, which points to the same object), it will append to the single object that those two references point to.  If you want to insert a *copy* of `q`, you can use slicing like so:

```
p=[1,q[:],4]
```

or

```
p.append(q[:])
```

This will create a new anonymous list that you can append to without affecting the original or any other reference to that same object that `q` points to.

Here's an example:

```
>>> q = [2, 3]
>>> p = [1, q[:], 4]      # include a copy of q using [:]
>>> p[1].append('test')   # append to copy
>>> p
[1, [2, 3, 'test'], 4]    # 'test' is in p[1]
>>> q 
[2, 3]                    # but not in q
>>> p = [1, q, 4]         # include q itself in p (no [:])
>>> p[1].append('test')
>>> p
[1, [2, 3, 'test'], 4]    # test appears in p[1]
>>> q
[2, 3, 'test']            # and also in q
```

Comment: I clarified the wording in your answer a bit - it's not really "a reference to `q`" - `q` is the name that *holds* the reference to an object.

Comment: @LukasGraf thanks for the edit, the wording on this kind of thing is always a little muddy for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can explain. Your `p` keeps reference to `q` and you cannot change that. That's all. So if you will edit `p[1]`, then basically it modifies `q`, because going there through reference.

**Any document can help understand the above behaviour?**
https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html

**I have no idea why python did this?**

To have two ways of doing things. 
Based on reference to object (you don't pass a copy of `q` to `p`, just only reference):

```
>>> q=[2,3]
>>> p=[1,q,4]
>>> p[1].append('test')
>>> q
[2, 3, 'test']
```

and without (you pass a copy of `q` to `p`, not reference):

```
>>> q=[2,3]
>>> p=[1,q[:],4]
>>> p[1].append('test')
>>> q
[2, 3]
```

**In which cases, this behaviour will happen?**

I think example above shows it.

Comment: Yes, any more details about this? I have no idea why python did this? and In which cases, it did this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Python you may run into issues like this.

In Python if you say

```
    a = [10]
```

And then say

```
    b = a
```

What happens? b gets the value of a, but also any change in a will make the similar change in b, because instead of just copying the value "b" is pointed towards "a" (that means changes in a will reflect in b as well)
That is the reason why you are facing that issue.

In case you don't want this you can use copy module in python

```
    from copy import copy

    b = copy(a)
```

Now even though you change the value of "a", "b" value will be same.

[For any reference regarding the same topic](http://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php)